# visual studio intellisense doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I'm developing with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, Resharper and Xamarin and since a few days I have a very strange behaviour. Visual Studio tells me everytime that the entered code is wrong and Intellisens doesn't work anymore. 
This happens since a crash of visual studio.

Visual Studio marks me everything in red and if I look at the tooltip, then it shows: "Module 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f12d51a3b' should be referenced"

If I remove the .suo file, then it works until the project is closed and reopened again.

Does someone has an idea on solving it?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be something related to Resharper or Xamarin references missing in your project. Please check. I have also found people saying that this issue gets resolved permanently after they restarted their PCs. I know this is weird, but if you can try and confirm these.

Comment: The restart doesn't work, it's still their. Just if I remove the suo-File, then it works until I close the project and open it again. 
It also happens on projects with Windows Forms or WPF, so it's not just Xamarin projects.

Answer (score -2):

I think reinstalling Visual Studio will solve your problem.

*Otherwise its a problem that should be addressed to the visual studio support and not the SO*